# Replacing values in a column based on another column, no else only if

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have dataset of a full year of dates starting in September spanning a full 365 days:

**dates**

| date | dayname | daytype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | Thur | weekday |
| 2022-09-02 | Fri | weekday |
| 2022-09-03 | Sat | weekend/holiday |
| 2022-09-04 | Sun | weekend/holiday |
| 2022-09-05 | Mon | weekday |

I have run a ifelse line of code to assign weekdays or weekends/holidays:

`dates$daytype <- ifelse(dates$dayname %in% c("Sat","Sun"), "weekend/holiday", "weekday")`

My issue now is that some dates are holidays but cannot be defined that by an easy line of code like above. How can I change the daytype of holidays to reflect weekend/holiday in the daytype column.

The code I have tried is this but has an else factor I have to assign so I can't just change these dates I'm looking at:

````
  daytype = case_when(
    date %in% c(2022-09-05,2022-11-11,2022-11-24,2022-12-26,2023-01-02, 2023-1-16,2023-02-20,2023-05-14,2023-06-19,
                202-07-04) ~ "Weekend/Holiday"))```
````

Comment: There are multiple packages that list the holidays (for diffrent country, etc.) for each year, [timeDate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/timeDate.pdf) is one of them.    Not clear about the geographic location from your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` again, e.g.

**If dates is a `character`-type:**

```r
dates$daytype <- ifelse(
                        dates$date %in% c("2022-09-05",
                                          "2022-11-11",
                                          "2022-11-24",
                                          "2022-12-26",
                                          "2023-01-02",
                                          "2023-01-16",
                                          "2023-02-20",
                                          "2023-05-14",
                                          "2023-06-19",
                                          "2002-07-04"),
                         "Weekend/Holiday",
                         dates$daytype
                         )
```

**If it is a `date`-type:**

```r
dates$daytype <- ifelse(
                        dates$date %in% as.Date(c("2022-09-05",
                                                  "2022-11-11",
                                                  "2022-11-24",
                                                  "2022-12-26",
                                                  "2023-01-02",
                                                  "2023-01-16",
                                                  "2023-02-20",
                                                  "2023-05-14",
                                                  "2023-06-19",
                                                  "2002-07-04")),
                         "Weekend/Holiday",
                         dates$daytype
                         )
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  date       dayname daytype        
  <date>     <chr>   <chr>          
1 2022-09-01 Thur    weekday        
2 2022-09-02 Fri     weekday        
3 2022-09-03 Sat     weekend/holiday
4 2022-09-04 Sun     weekend/holiday
5 2022-09-05 Mon     Weekend/Holiday
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

dates <- read_table("date   dayname daytype
2022-09-01  Thur    weekday
2022-09-02  Fri weekday
2022-09-03  Sat weekend/holiday
2022-09-04  Sun weekend/holiday
2022-09-05  Mon weekday")
```